# Visualflow save and return

Tags: visual-workflow

Is it possible to save and return to a set point in a visual flow...eg. get halfway thru the flow, save, return later to save point in the flow.

Is there any way to accomplish that using flows?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you allow the interview to show the "pause" button, salesforce provides native support to pause and resume the flow. You can read about it in the [release notes](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_pause.htm) where this feature came out (Spring 15), and check out the [flow:interview](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_flow_interview.htm) documentation on parameters you can use to allow pausing (`allowShowPause`) and resuming (`pausedInterviewId`).

Comment: Thank you. That looks like it will work. I'm testing it now.